# How to re-arrange text in this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

I want to rearrange the below text to read  "Split Screen" instead of "Screen Split".

How do I do that in Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming your asking this question because you don't have access to the 'text layer' and that you have a 'flat layered image'.
so here are your steps

1. Clone your flat layer (background) by CMD-J  and call this layer 'chrome bg'
2. using the marque tool make a selection to cover 'screen' and hit CMD-J, this will clone the selection into a new layer... call this 'screen' and hide the layer
3. select the 'chrome bg' layer and follow step 2,.. but instead make a selection of 'split'...
4. now go to layer 'chrome bg' and using the heal/patch tool remove the 'screen split' text and clean the layer.
5. switch the visibility of all 3 newly created layers. You should now have 3 layers which should allow you to reposition and clean as needed.

Hope this helps
cheers

Comment: Yes. I don't have access to text layer as this is a flat image. Thanks for your steps. Let me check it.